# Form validation does not happen

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, validation

My form has some fields that are mandatory and I have marked them with `class="required"`. I am writing the below jquery to validate this form, but it doesn't happen. I think either I am messing with calling the two functions or I am not getting the proper element through `$(this)`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validatemyForm() {
        $('.required').each(function() {
            if($(this).val() == "" || $(this).replace(/\s/g, '').length == 0)
            {
                $(this).insertAfter('<span>This is a Required Filed</span>');
                return false;
            }
            else {
                $(this).remove();
            }
        })
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

I am calling the form, from the onsubmit event handler `<form id="myform" onsubmit ="return validatemyForm();">`. Am I incorrectly using `each` and `this` of jQuery?

Comment: What errors come up in the javascript console/firebug?

Comment: You are replacing the `$(this)` which isn't quite possible. Do you mean `$(this).val().replace`?

Comment: @Oded: Firebug doesn't show anyerror, but once I submit the form, I can temporarily see that first field with class = "required" disppears and comes back.

Comment: @pimvdb: I am not interested in $(this).val().replace I just added it to validate white spaces, Even if I remove it, I still have the same issue.

Comment: You're doing server side validation, right?

Comment: @Raynos: No, not at all. Is there any difference in calling a function from form id or submit button to validate, if server side validation is also in place

Comment: @user you should do server side validation. Client side validation is for direct feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A number of things:

1. You can use `replace` on a String, whilst you use it on a jQuery object. There is no `$(this).replace`. If you want to check for whitespace, you need the value, i.e. `$(this).val().replace`.
2. You use `$(this).insertAfter` which means that the input element is inserted after the span. `$(this).remove` simply removes the input element which isn't what you're after either I think.
3. You `return false` in the `each()`, but this doesn't return that value in the `validatemyForm` function. In that function, you always `return true`.

I changed it to this to get it working: http://jsfiddle.net/DaDQT/6/.

Answer (score 0):

Your function `validatemyForm` always returns true. The `return false` you have in there is inside the function passed to `each`. `validatemyForm`does not stop at this point.

The following should work as you expect it (untested code):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validatemyForm() {
        var ok = true;
        $('.required').each(function() {
            if($(this).val() == "" || $(this).val().replace(/\s/g, '').length == 0)
            {
                $(this).insertAfter('<span>This is a Required Field</span>');
                ok = false;
            }
            else {
                $(this).remove();
            }
        })
        return ok;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: No It will not As $(this).remove(); will remove all the text fields. Thanks to pimvdb

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I just copied the question code. I only changed things related to what the function would return.